# Is it possible to activate customfield 'text description' upon activating the customfield 'checkbox'?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, editor

I'm trying to find a solution how to activate a another customfield in WordPress pages when the selectbox is selected.

This is the script to simply show the customfield `'checkbox'` in wordpress page editor.

```
array(
    'name' => 'Lees meer button',
    'desc' => 'Leesbutton weergeven.',
    'id'   => $prefix . 'homepage_slider_leesmeer',
    'type' => 'checkbox',
),
```

What I want to achieve is to display a another customfield in the WordPress page editor, when the selectbox is checked.

How can this be done?

Comment: Even though the core of the problem is not specific to WP, I am certain you'd receive an answer in the form of a simple jQuery toggle, if you had supplied enough information. An array alone does not " simply show the customfield" though, that's just a piece of data...

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use jquery to show/hide your custom field, something like this:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#yourcheckboxidentifier').click(function() {
        $('#customfieldidentifier').fadeToggle(400);
    });
    if ($('#yourcheckboxidentifier').val() !== undefined) {
        $('#customfieldidentifier').show();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! However i don't have any experience on including a jquery function into a php file. Can you help me achieved this ?

Comment: How are you adding your custom fields?
Maybe adding the 'script' I wrote (after modifying it accordingly to your identifiers) at the end of your custom field file and surrounding it between: <script></script> will be enough.

Comment: I'm adding the customfield like this : 'id'         => 'Homepage_slider',
  'title'      => 'Slider afbeelding inhoud',
  'pages'      => array( 'homepage_slider'), // Post type
  'context'    => 'normal',
  'priority'   => 'high',
  'show_names' => true, // Show field names on the left
  'fields'     => array(
   array(
    'name' => 'Afbeelding',
    'desc' => 'Voeg een afbeelding toe.',
    'id'   => $prefix . 'homepage_slider_image',
    'type' => 'file',
   ),

Comment: @Laurens ok, but in which file are you adding it? Are you hardcoding it in your functions.php, in a separate file, in a plugin, using your mind.... (I am jocking).
Anyway just try to add the 'script' I sent you after your php code.

Comment: haha ;-p anyways I'm including a separate dashboard javascript file into the dashboard of wordpress. Trying to manipulate the selectors. But no success.. the javascript is correct but It doesn't overrule anything..When i change a selector in the dashboard by CSS it works. Somehow it doensn't do the trick javascript. Yes, the javascript file is included properly in the footer. Any advice ?

Comment: I noticed that using the $ symbol wordpress doesn't animate the script. A replacement with 'jquery' did the trick! I solved the problem! Thanks for the answers!

Comment: You are welcome, please accept my answer if the problem is solved. :)

Comment: The problem is almost solved, is there a way to give a specific ID to an customfield or an td selector in wordpress editor ?